# How I solve Magento 2 Auto load Error

Tags: magento2, varien-autoload

I have created a new Magento module and create a new theme in Magento but the auto-load error has come

[image]

Comment: You have permission issue at  system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
There might be 2 case
```

**1. Cache issue**

```
rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ 
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs/
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**2. Permission Issue**

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some permission issue with magento files and folder. Try to change permission as follow

```
cd <your Magento install dir> 

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory 

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder    

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R :<web server group> .

chmod u+x bin/magento
```